# the picture is stretched in imageview android

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

i want to make animation with two pictures, but they are steretched. When i open this image like src in imageView- all is ok(image 1) , but when i run animation - it steretced(image 2).

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_exercise_info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="238dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

I try to set scaleType  fitXY, but it does not help me. Sory for my english.

[image: animation]
[image: when i open this image like sourse in imageView]

Comment: what folder i must to create? drawable-nodpi?

Comment: under `res` folder, create new folder--> name it `drawable-nodpi`, and place your images in it

Comment: it doesn't help me=( 
when i set android: width="120 dp"?all is ok.

Comment: no, it's bad, becouse another picture has anoter width, that's why i need to keep aspect ratio

Comment: I said it good because, you said `all is ok` ...I know it is bad solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picture is stretched in imageview android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373571/picture-is-stretched-in-imageview-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think layout defined for imageview is where the issue is. Try this.

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_exercise_info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="238dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: When i set android:layout_width="wrap_content" - imageView is empty

Comment: @KostyaKhuta yes, because you haven't specify default image by using `android:src` attribute of imageview

Comment: imv.setBackgroundDrawable(myAnimation);  When i set default picture in imageView, it will be bad, becouse one image in front, animation in background

Answer (score 0):

Use following :-
    android:id="@+id/iv_exercise_info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="238dp"
    android:ScaleType="CENTER"